# yasm, using 64bit register as pointer to list and having the offset be a 32bit register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, yasm

I'm having trouble moving some of my previous code into a global function in assembly. I have an algorithm that accepts `len` and `lst` where `len` is the length of the list and `lst` is the list of double words itself. Before moving it into a function I was using

`dword[lst+edi*4] ; offset`

But now that `lst` is passed into `rdi` writing

`dword[rdi+edi*4]` gives me an error "Error: invalid effective address"

what can I do to avoid this ?

Comment: `rdi` and `edi` are parts of the same register.  So if `rdi` is the address of `lst`, then you shouldn't be using `edi` to hold the index.  Just use another register instead.

Comment: You can't mix sizes. You can choose between a 32bit address and a 64bit address, that is all. So either all registers used in a memory operand must be 64bit, or they must all be 32bit, and the latter is rarely useful and not well known.